# Pandas append data frames, add a field, and then flood the field with a default value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several data frames that contain all of the same column names.  I want to append them into a master data frame.  I also want to create a column that denotes the original field and then flood it with the original data frames name.  I have some code that works.

```
df_combine = df_breakfast.copy()
df_combine['X_ORIG_DF'] = 'Breakfast'
df_combine = df_combine.append(df_lunch, ignore_index=True)
df_combine['X_ORIG_DF'] = df_combine['X_ORIG_DF'].fillna('Lunch')
# Rinse and repeat
```

However, it seems inelegant.  I was hoping someone could point me to a more elegant solution.  Thank you in advance for your time!

***Note:** Edited to reflect comment!*

Comment: Note: your first line is overridden by the second, and the third line *changes* `df_breakfast`, which may or may not be acceptable...

Comment: The first line was a copy mistake but the second was a real mistake!  Thank you for the catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely consider restructuring you data in a way the names can be accessed neatly rather than as variable names (if they *must* be separate to begin with).
For example a dictionary:

```
d = {'breakfast': df_breakfast, 'lunch': df_lunch}
```

Create a function to give each DataFrame a new column:

```
def add_col(df, col_name, col_entry):
    df = df.copy() # so as not to change df_lunch etc.
    df[col_name] = col_entry
    return df
```

and combine the list of DataFrame each with the appended column (`'X_ORIG_DF'`):

```
In [3]: df_combine = pd.DataFrame().append(list(add_col(v, 'X_ORIG_DF', k)
                                           for k, v in d.items()))
Out[3]: 
   0  1  X_ORIG_DF
0  1  2      lunch
1  3  4      lunch
0  1  2  breakfast
1  3  4  breakfast
```

*In this example: `df_lunch = df_breakfast = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])`.*

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a similar problem as you when trying to combine multiple files together for the purpose of analysis in a master dataframe. Here is one method for creating that master dataframe by loading each dataframe independently, giving them each an identifier in a column called 'ID' and combining them. If your data is a list of files in a directory called `datadir` I would do the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_list = os.listdir(datadir)
df_dict = {}

for data_file in data_list:
    df = read_table(data_file)
    #add an ID column based on the file name.
    #you could use some other naming scheme of course 
    df['ID'] = data_file
    df_dict[data_file] = df

#the concat function is great for combining lots of dfs. 
#it takes a list of dfs as an argument.
combined_df_with_named_column = pd.concat(df_dict.values())
```